# where to get a uefi shell/bootloader executable

Tags: grub, uefi, bootloader

I have a laptop [hp elitebook 8440p] formally running slax, hoping to run alpine.
I'm in a situation where I don't have my USBoot key [recovery flash stick] only a fat32 8GB flash storage and a stock android phone with an otg adapter to copy files to it.

Now the laptop is in a state where the primary partition is overwritten by an alpine install iso [by no mistake] and on another partition I have a backup of a functioning system.
How do I reflash the backup using only a phone, some flash memory, an efi compliant laptop and the wild wild web

I have tried the openboot and tianacore shellx64.efi but no luck, I tried to get precompiled grub with no luck.

Comment: Does the alpine install actually boot, or do you get dumped into the UEFI prompt?

Comment: Neither, "linuxboot.iso not found" and continues to pxe then "non bootable disk insert bootable disk and try again"

Answer (score 0):

Fn hockey  stix, while booting opencore's `/efi/boot/bootx64.efi` would return me to the boot screen, had I checked to see that `/efi/oc/tools` had the actual `shellx64.efi` I wouldnt even have asked.

Anyway, is some dumdum gets the same issue as me, the opencore tools folder also contains the shell that I needed